# How to build plasma netbook?

Tags: kde, plasma

i got source code of kde-workspace from repository as below:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep kde-workspace
apt-get source kde-workspace
```

And then, i switched to plasma netbook shell source directory, and run cmake:

```
cd kde-workspace/plasma/netbook/shell
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
```

And after this, i get error:

> CMake Error at nettoolbox/CMakeLists.txt:7 (kde4_add_plugin):
>    Unknown CMake command "kde4_add_plugin".
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

It's possible to build plasma netbook separately from kde-workspace?